# Do you have an account on Facebook/ on YouTube/ on Twitter/ on Intragram/ Google+?

Tags: prepositions, idioms

Is it correct to use 'on' before all the social networking sites?
Can I use any other prepositions?

Comment: Yes, you do use "on" for all of them.

Comment: Or, much more prevalent: "Do you have a Facebook account?" (and similar for the other ones.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use **"or**" between the social networking sites, which is a conjunction:

> "Do you have an account on Facebook or Twitter?"

If you are asking about multiple sites, then use a comma between the sites, and "or" before the last one:

> "Do you have an account on Facebook, Twitter, Youtube, or Instagram?"

Comment: The question was about "on" and not "or". It's a good phrase, though.